# spark Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaRDD<Object> to JavaRDD<String>

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

I have started to write my Pyspark application to Java implementation. I am using Java 8. I just started to execute some of the basic spark progrma in java. I used the following [wordcount](http://ingini.org/2015/05/04/apache-spark-java-8-streams-overview/)  example.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Work Count App");

// Create a Java version of the Spark Context from the configuration
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(filename);

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")))
                    .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2(word, 1))
                    .reduceByKey((x, y) -> (Integer) x + (Integer) y)
                    .sortByKey();
```

I am getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaRDD<Object> to JavaRDD<String>` error in `lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")))`
When i googled, in all the Java 8 based spark example, i saw the same above implementation.What went wrong in my environemnt or the program.

Can some one help me ?

Comment: Is `sc` a `JavaSparkContext` instance.

Comment: @Ravikumar, Yes  it is JavaSparkContext.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this code. Actual issue is rdd.flatMap function expects `Iterator<String>` while your code is creating `List<String>`. Calling the iterator() will fix the problem.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator())
            .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1))
            .reduceByKey((x, y) ->  x +  y)
            .sortByKey();

counts.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println(data._1()+"-"+data._2());
    });
```

Comment: Can you please add one line of explaination

Comment: @Backtrack I have added the detail.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
JavaRDD<String> words =
    lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts =
    words.mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(w, 1))
         .reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaRDD<String> obj = jsc.textFile("<Text File Path>");
JavaRDD<String> obj1 = obj.flatMap(l->{
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
String[] str = l.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<str/length;i++) {
    al.add(str[i]);
}
return al.iterator();
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you can write down a helpful comment in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(
                new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                    public Iterator<String> call(String s) {
                        return (Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator());
                    }
                } );
```